# enabled action after disabled it by preventDefault

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a problem with preventDefault(); i'm new with this use, in my function i keep error of a validation form in a array and display it in a modal window, if error exist i cancel the action on the link, but i don't know how remove this preventDefault when i'm in the 'else'

Thx

```
if(array.length != 0){
    //for cancel action on the link
    $('body').on('click','div.linkGet a',function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
    });
    //tranform the array in html and put it in the html
    $.colorbox({
        href:"../../tpl/validation-form.twig",
        width:450,
        onComplete:function(){
            $(array).each(function(index, item) {
                $("#wrapperValidationForm ul").append($("<li>").html(item));
                $.colorbox.resize();
            });                                                     
        }
    });
}
else{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use .on function you bind an event handler (the function) to the event (clicking the 'a' element), so once bound the handler function will be executed every time the event is triggered (preventing the default action). What I believe you need here is to unbind the handler from the event as such:

```
$('body div.linkGet a').unbind('click');
```

Note that this will remove every handler for the click event. You might also want to make your selectors a little neater, for example like this:

```
$('div.linkGet').click(function(ev) {
   // stuff here
});
```

and

```
$('div.linkGet a').unbind('click');
```

since I assume the div lies within the body of the document.

Comment: It's `.unbind` instead of `.unbound`

Comment: Thanks kei, fixed that